# Image Effects for Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, imagemagick, effects

I am making an app which will allow the user to click a picture and then apply various effect filters on the picture. Basically, I want to create an app similar to [Pudding Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kth.PuddingCamera&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rdGguUHVkZGluZ0NhbWVyYSJd).

I researched a lot and came across 3 options to do this:-

1) Use OpenCV and implement all the effects manually [not my first priority as it uses a lot of time, but will do this if all else is unfruitful].

2) Use a library like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) / [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) / [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/) by porting to Android via NDK.

3) Use a library like [jjil](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/).

Now I want to know which is the best way to proceed. My priorities are:-

1) I want to be able to tweak the effects and maybe create new custom effects of my own.

2) I want it to run fast as I want my app to be quick and responsive.

3) I want to use a library which is easiest to learn as I am not an expert in image proccesing.

Please help!

Comment: Though your been a member you 2+ years, I noticed this is your first question. According to [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/), questions that "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific coding question please ask it, be sure to post the relevant code and any errors.

Comment: @Sam I'd say this is borderline though since he's providing the options. What's missing is some research on his part :p

Comment: @ColeJohnson I have tried using OpenCV on Android using NDK, and though I am getting basic effects like Canny Edge Detection and Inverse Sobel Effect, but I do not know how to progress to the advanced effects from here. Any book or resource which teaches how to implement effects like chalk effect, neon effect, glass effect?

Comment: i think @kpsfoo can use Aviary SDK http://www.aviary.com/android

Comment: @kpsfoo hey I want to do the same as you ask into your question. Can you please help me with OpenCV I am new to use it and I dont know how to implement that into my application. If you share Example code then it will be better for understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV works well for Android 2.3 and beyond, you can consider FastCV by Qualcomm, which is like OpenCV but more optimized for Qualcomm chips. 
I don't not recommend JJIL, it hasn't been updated for ever and only works on very old version of Android.

Comment: Thanks DXM! I am using OpenCV with NDK for now and it is working well :) Thanks to others for helping too :)